# PHPMailer Error (Could not authenticate.)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send E-Mail using PHPMalier. but it Showing me Errors. and I am sure that my E-mail and my Password are Correct. I tried every solution on Youtube, Google and even in StackOverflow but nothing helped me. PHP is kinda new for me so I don't know PHP very much.

here is the main Error

```
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 
Please log in via your web browser  
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
 2018-05-16 13:11:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
   2018-05-16 13:11:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection i1- 
   v6sm5130251pfi.133 - gsmtp
  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
  Email Error.INFO:SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

And Here is my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php

 require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$developmentMode = true;
$mailer = new PHPMailer($developmentMode);

 try {
  $mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mailer->isSTMP();


 if ($developmentMode) {

         $mailer->SMTPOptions = [
           'ssl'=> [
              'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
          'allow_self_signed' => true
        ]
     ];

    } 

    $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
      $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com";
    $mailer->Password = "password";
      $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mailer->Port = 587;

      $mailer-> setFrom("mygmail@gmail.com", "Izaya");
      $mailer->addAddress("anothergmail@gmail.com","orihara");

    $mailer->isHTML(true);
     $mailer->Subject = "Hey There";
    $mailer->Body = "NICE TO MEET YOU IZAYA ";


   $mailer->send();
  $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
   echo "Mail has been Sent";



      }catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Email Error.INFO:" . $mailer->ErrorInfo;

  }


 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The clue is in "Log in via your web browser". Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), which discusses that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable access for the less secure apps in your gmail account settings to be able to send email from your PHP script.

You can refer to this google doc page to see how to enable it:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en